# Emulator for galaxy s3

Tags: android, emulation, samsung-mobile

Has Samsumg provided emulator support for galaxy s3. I want to test my app on S3 Emulator as I'm reading the comments on google play that the app is crashing on Samsung Galaxy S3. Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any logs? It's probably impossible to emulate the actual device, just something close to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use the samsung remote test lab

[Samsung Remote Test Tab](http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do)

OR
 this link for your Support
[Here](http://www.perfectomobile.com) (It gives 1 hour free trial to test your app.)

**EDITED**

For Emulator you can Use Below Informations.

**Target: Google APIs - API Level 15 Skin: Built-in WXGA720**

```
Hardware Back/Home: yes
Abstracted LCD density: 320
Keyboard lid support: no
Max VM application heap size: 48
Device ram size: 1024
```

Comment: I think, with the settings you provided, it will not behave like S3. It will just has S3's specifications.

Comment: yes you are Right Raghav. I have Edited My Answer you can also view http://www.perfectomobile.com/ link to get free Trial.

Comment: RTL is pretty limited - I've looked at using it for three different apps. Each time, the devices didn't have a feature the apps needed. And, Raghav is correct about the specs. Too often, in my experience, the emulator runs code as expected, but the real device does not :-(. Less frequent, the emulator is broken, but same code works on device. Of course, your milage may vary... and if it's a Samsung, you may feel like you're riding in a car that has square wheels.

Answer (score 2):

//you can simply set your emulator settings as

`WXGA720` skin with a Abstract LCD density of 320.